# How to put String [] Array in JsonObject Post Request of Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using `Volley` to Post data to Api.I need to post Json Object.The Json Object consist of one String Array.The format of my `JSON` object for `POST` request is

```
{
"id":"00001",
"roles":["1", "2", "4"],
"notes":"special"
}
```

My String  [] is in form of `String roles[]=["11", "3"]`.
My Json Post Request is

```
private void assign() {
        String url = "";
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("id",id);
            object.put("roles",roles);
            object.put("no_people",people);
            object.put("notes","special");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        })
```

I am getting error code 400 while posting for roles object.How to construct this object for post request ?

Comment: code 400 service not working

Comment: Maybe when you post  **roles**  as the string but actually it contains symbols so backed is not responsible for taking a string which contains the symbol, the best way is to remove open braces and your backend will break easily by comma.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do to add an array to my JSON:

Create a JSONArray for your roles array that you'll put in your main JSONObject.
You then just have to iterate on your roles's array, adding each element to your newly created JSONArray before adding it to your JSONObject:

```
JSONArray tmp = new JSONArray();
for (i=0, i<roles.length, i++)
  tmp.put(roles[i]);
object.put("roles", tmp);
```

Not sure if it's really what you are asking for tho, i feel like your post and it's title doesn't ask for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("tag", "test");

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);
```

add parameter like this